# how to get all child and grand child elements from parent ID in linq

Tags: sql, linq

Hello I am updating my question for better explanation.

I have table structure having parent child relationship like this

[image]

i have  created module class like this

```
 class MenuModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public string MenuItem { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public List<MenuModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

now i want to list of root node Reordering Services having menuid 10.

This is what i have done yet

```
 List<MenuModel> lstMenu = new List<MenuModel>();
        NeelamWPFEntities _entity = new NeelamWPFEntities();
        var recordlist = _entity.Menus.Where(x => x.MenuID == 10 || x.ParentID == 10).ToList();

        foreach (var item in recordlist)
        {

            MenuModel objMenu = new MenuModel();
            objMenu.ID = item.ID;
            objMenu.MenuID = item.MenuID;
            objMenu.MenuItem = item.MenuItem;
            objMenu.ParentID = item.ParentID;
            objMenu.ImagePath = item.ImagePath;
            lstMenu.Add(objMenu);


        }
        lstMenu.ForEach(v => v.Children = lstMenu.Where(vv => vv.ParentID.Equals(v.MenuID)).ToList());
        lstMenu = lstMenu.Where(u => u.ParentID == null).ToList();

        return lstMenu;
```

by this way i will get 2 level child only.how do i get N level childs of root Reordering Services.

Plaese Help,
Thankx

Comment: That's recursive, it means your table isn't well designed.

Comment: You need [recursive CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=recursive+cte+linq) which has no LINQ support.

Comment: y not well designed. i provided parent-child relationship.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you do some thing like that

```
foreach(var correctParent in recordlist){
   var grandChild = _entity.Menus.Where(x => x.ParentID == correctParent.MenuID).ToList();
   //add your grandChild in a listOfAllGrandChild ...
    }
```

Adding all your grandChild in a single entity and then sum both your grandChild and recordList, and do a distinct on it ?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i have updated my que pls check.it will explain better